# How to access java-classes in the default-package?

Tags: java, groovy, default-package

I'm working now together with others in a grails project. I have to write some Java-classes. But I need access to an searchable object created with groovy. It seems, that this object has to be placed in the default-package.

My question is: **Is there a way to access this object in the default-package from a Java-class in a named package?**

Answer (score 136, accepted):

[You can’t use](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/import.html) classes in the default package from a named package.
(*Technically* you can, as shown in Sharique Abdullah's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561183/6309) through reflection API, *but* classes from the unnamed namespace are **not in scope** in an **import declaration**)

Prior to J2SE 1.4 you could import classes from the default package using a syntax like this:

```
import Unfinished;
```

That's [no longer allowed](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4989710). So to access a default package class from within a packaged class requires moving the default package class into a package of its own.

If you have access to the source generated by groovy, some post-processing is needed to move the file into a dedicated package and add this "package" directive at its beginning.

---

Update 2014: [bug 6975015](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6975015), for JDK7 and JDK8, describe an even *stricter* prohibition against import from unnamed package.

> The `TypeName` must be the canonical name of a class type, interface type, enum type, or annotation type.
> The type must be either a member of a **named package**, or a member of a type whose outermost lexically enclosing type is a member of a **named package**, **or a compile-time error occurs**.

---

[Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package/283828#comment98446842_283828):

> > "why is [the default package] there in the first place? design error?"
>
> No, it's deliberate.
> [JLS 7.4.2. Unnamed Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.2) says: "Unnamed packages are provided by the Java SE platform principally for convenience when developing small or temporary applications or when just beginning development".

Comment: As I've explained to other people before, the default package is a second-class citizen in the Java world. Just Don't Do That. :-)

Comment: Seems I have to learn Groovy (on a very time-constrained project) or code in the default-package. :-(

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young if so why is it there in the first place? design error?

Comment: Why it was deprecated?

Comment: @SuzanCioc do you mean: "why after J2SE1.4, can you no longer access the default package?"

Comment: @VonC yes this is what I mean

Comment: @SuzanCioc Because classes from the unnamed namespace are not in scope in an import declaration: the risk of *naming collision* was simply too important in that unnamed namespace.

Comment: @VonC what is the principal difference between "root" package and any other top-level packages, like `com` or `org`? May be let us prohibit to import them too?

Comment: @SuzanCioc `com` or `org` are based on a naming *convention*, as opposed to the "`root`" package, which is part of the language specification. You have to trust conventions, but the language can evolve its specification.

Comment: I agree that both conventions ans specifications can evolve. So if we judge to evolve root package specification because of dangerous name clash, then we can evolve conventions on the same reason: NEVER put your class into one-level named package or you will be in danger!

Comment: @SuzanCioc I agree. The difference, though, is that conventions evolve by their *users*, while specifications evolves by the language designers: two different communities, both in scale and in decision process.

Comment: Downvote because although I agree with the sentament, Sharique's answer is correct and this one is wrong.

Comment: @BillK Good point. i have included a reference to Sharique's answer. I have also documented a recent (2014) evolution of JLS8 (Java Language Specification) reinforcing the fact a type *must* be a member of a type package.

Comment: Thanks, -1 removed... I wonder how the JLS change will affect Groovy scripts because they are generally in the default package (It wouldn't make much sense to have them anywhere else). I suppose groovy could assign a fake package automatically--that would be no more hacky than anything else in groovy :)

Comment: @VonC, Aside from reflection, what about the new invocation mechanisms?

Comment: @VonC, Yep, I heard they gave dynamic coding a complete rehaul, making scripting languages like JS, Scala, and Kotlin First class.

Comment: @Pacerier "why is [the default package] there in the first place? design error?" No, it's deliberate. JLS [7.4.2. Unnamed Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.2) says: *"Unnamed packages are provided by the Java SE platform principally for **convenience** when developing **small or temporary applications** or when just **beginning development**"*.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 63):

In fact, you can.

Using reflections API you can access any class so far. At least I was able to :)

```
Class fooClass = Class.forName("FooBar");
Method fooMethod = fooClass.getMethod("fooMethod", String.class);

String fooReturned = (String)fooMethod.invoke(fooClass.newInstance(), "I did it");
```

Comment: For Scala, the following code works: `val bar = "hi";
    val fooClass = Class.forName("FooClass");
    val fooMethod = fooClass.getMethod("foo", classOf[Array[String]]);
    val fooReturned = fooMethod.invoke(fooClass.newInstance(), Array(bar));`

Comment: Great answer, +1. Since the question was groovy, however, you can use duck typing (like Duct taping I guess)... `Class.forName("FooBar").newInstance().fooMethod("I did it")`

Comment: Well, if I have two classes named FooBar from two differents jar files, which one will be called?

Answer (score 7):

Use [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to repackage the jar file with the following rule:

```
rule * <target package name>.@1
```

All classes in the default package of the source jar file will move to the target package, thus are able to access.

Comment: a demo of how to use jarjar would be great

Comment: @BiGGZ: See the [README.md](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar/blob/master/README.md) file on the jarjar github repo to see how to use jarjar with ant, gradle or the command line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use packages in the `Groovy` code, and things will work just fine.

It may mean a minor reorganization of code under `grails-app` and a little bit of a pain at first, but on a large grails project, it just make sense to organize things in packages.  We use the Java standard package naming convention `com.foo.<app>.<package>`.

Having everything in the default package becomes a hindrance to integration, as you're finding.

Controllers seem to be the one Grails artifact (or artefact) that resists being put in a Java package.  Probably I just haven't figured out the `Convention` for that yet.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*just to complete the idea:*

**From inside** default-package you can access objects resided in named packages.