# import from another java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I'm working on two projects in eclipse and I would like to import some classes from project a to project b. What should I do?

Is there a way of doing it without adding the project to the build path ?

Comment: can you clarify how to import class from another project ? I'm getting error The import can not be resolved

Comment: Found the problem; I didn't specify any package for class in the project which I had included under Projects. Found this issue through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335211/what-is-the-default-package-in-which-my-classes-are-put-if-i-dont-specify-it

Answer (score 103, accepted):

add project A to project B's build path.

Follow these steps:
Edits by `@David B`
Right click on project B's folder in eclipse --> properties --> build path --> projects --> add.
Now add project A

Comment: thanks! just to be more explicit for future reference of other readers: right click on project b's folder in eclipse --> properties --> build path --> projects --> add.

Comment: i followed your solution and i got `a cycle was detected in the build path`.

Comment: By `Build Path` do you mean `Java Build Path`?

Comment: There's some trouble following [ozk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/408717/ozk) solution but [David B](http://stackoverflow.com/users/377031/david-b) is much better.

Comment: @bouncingHippo I think that mean you have both files importing each other.

Comment: What about adding a dependency via pom file? Mine is a maven project.

Comment: can you please clarify how to import class from project a into the class of project b ? Classes which I want to import are public

Comment: Found the problem; I didn't specify any package for class in the project which I had included under Projects. Found this issue through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335211/what-is-the-default-package-in-which-my-classes-are-put-if-i-dont-specify-it

Comment: When using PyDev: Right click on project folder -> PYTHONPATH -> External Libraries -> Add Source Folder