# How to import package in eclipse (Import package can not be resolved)

Tags: java

Package 1:

```
package Mypackage;

public class MyFirst {
    int a;
    MyFirst()
    {
      a=10; 
    }
}
```

Package 2:

```
package mySecondPackage;
import Mypackage.MyFirst;
public class MySecond extends MyFirst{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

I got one error that is The import Mypackage cannot be resolved.

Comment: Are your package 1 and 2 in the same project? If not you need to link package 1 to the project of package 2.

Comment: No...both are in different project..

Comment: As you said they are different project so one thing you can do is make a jar of the first project and place it in the classpath of second project

Comment: how to first project into classpath of second project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [import from another java project in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487585/import-from-another-java-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Then in the classpath of second project, add first project..
It must resolve your problem :)
Steps to fix it,
 Open project properties(ALT+Enter) -> left side check for java build path --> Project tab right side and then add first project..

Comment: why do you answer a 100% duplicate?

Comment: That's true.. I didn't search this site for duplicates before i answer.. Will check in future before answer general/common questions raised by developers..

Answer (score -2):

your superclass constructor is not visible that's why it is giving error..try this...

```
  package pack1;

 public class MyFirst {
  int a;
  public MyFirst()
{
  a=10; 
 }

}


package pack2;
import pack1.MyFirst;
public class MySecond extends MyFirst{


public static void main(String[] args) {
  MySecond s= new MySecond();

 }

 }
```

Comment: Wrong, his problem is actually that both packages are in different projects.

Comment: but he didn't mention both are in different project.