# Cucumber Predefined steps usage

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have a project where I have written some per-defined steps and implemented.

Now I like to use the per-defined steps in another project in eclipse. Kindly let me know how could I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487585/import-from-another-java-project-in-eclipse.

Comment: Do u want to import the step in project1 from project2?

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber only knows how to read and execute your feature files because of the step definition files usually defined with in a steps directory. That is where your feature statements are captured by regular expressions and translated to Java code
 The steps Cucumber will search for just live in a package, or a sub-package from the runner.
 Suggestion would be to copy the step definitions from Project 2 into your steps directory in Project 1.
 Also there is way to re-use steps is therefore to package the steps in a jar and add that jar as a dependency. You can use Maven for creating the jar.