# Need the same Class in 2 projects - Java

Tags: java, import, package

My question is kind of simple, and actually I'm feeling a bit dumb for asking this...

I'm using Eclipse IDE and I have 2 projects: `MarketServer` and `MarketClient` (I'm working with TCP connecting and sockets).

I've created a class called `Costumer`, which I need in both projects, in the same package of MarketServer (and inside the same project). How can I let both projects knowing that class? Do I have to create a isolated package just for `Costumer` and then import into both projects? How do I do that?

EDIT: Where do I place the new package that contains `Costumer`?

Sorry about my english, but I've tried my best :(

Comment: Yes use a separate package if it is a distinctly separate part of the overall program, and use import that class where needed.

Comment: I think this will help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255265/can-we-call-another-project-java-class-from-our-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The exact steps vary depending on what IDE you're using, but here's the basic idea: you need to create a separate project with the `Customer` class and whatever classes are shared between your `MarketServer` and `MarketClient` projects. That separate project needs to be compiled into a *library*, and then you can either manually (using the tools your IDE provides) or automatically (using a build tool like Maven) set up dependencies in your `MarketServer` and `MarketClient` projects that point to that new library.

Answer (score 0):

Create a jar(or zip of src folder) of source project where your original class is there.. and add this jar in other project.
But this way whenever you change source class, you need to previous step (creating jar/zip) again.

Or else, use ant or maven script, which will do earlier mentioned steps for you automatically whenever you build(compile) your source project.