# Java import a class from a different project but with the same package name

Tags: java, import, package, project

I work with Eclipse (Java) on different projects at the same time, let's name them **Project1** and **Project2**.

I'm working on Project1 and I want to import a **Class** inside a package '**a.b.c**' from Project2 : '**a.b.c.Class**'
Meanwhile, it seems that I got a package named '**a.b**' inside my Project1.

This cause an error because when i'm typing :

```
import a.b.c.Class
```

It seems like Eclipse thinks that I'm trying to refer to my package **'a.b' from Project1** instead of my package **'a.b.c' from Project2**. Eclipse wants me to create a package named 'a.b.c' in Project 1. And indeed when I try to build my project, there is an error.

I know that the packages shouldn't be named like this, but unfortunately it is...
Is it possible in any way to import the class I want in my project ?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is not the package name, Eclipse just ignores random projects unless you tell it to use them. See the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I thought the problem was the package name but it was just the fact that Project2 was not in the dependencies of Project1.. Thanks  [Tom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom)

[Can we call another project java class from our project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255265/can-we-call-another-project-java-class-from-our-project-in-eclipse)

It was a maven project, so I added in the pom.xml my dependency and it solved it.