# How can I use a Java class file from a different directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I'm currently programming a java programm in eclipse and have a java class file that can read Strings.
The file is not a system file and I'm looking for a solution to import that file without copying it into the project directory. Is there a posibility to do that in Java or in eclipse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we call another project java class from our project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255265/can-we-call-another-project-java-class-from-our-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

You can make that class a dependency using something like Maven: https://maven.apache.org/

OR

You can make a Jar from that class and add it to the classpath manually

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it!

Comment: This post answers your question in more detail, good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255265/can-we-call-another-project-java-class-from-our-project-in-eclipse