# How do I call a main function of project A into project B?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I have two spring-boot projects, lets call them A and B. I want to call a main function of of project A into of the functions of project B.

I have tried doing everything using this link:
[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255265/can-we-call-another-project-java-class-from-our-project-in-eclipse)

I still end up getting, `package does not exist`. Once when I did get it running for once, when I made a rest call I got `NoClassDefFoundError` error.

Comment: please clarify what do you want to do ? do you need multi-module project for example ? if that's what you need please check this https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Comment: seems like you are asking about how we can add one module as dependency into another. Try this link .. https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm