# Hibernate hbm mapping file referencing entity in another project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, hbm

I have two projects in an Eclipse workspace: 'myproject-main' references 'myproject-domain' (It is referenced by adding it to the build path. 'myproject-domain' contains my domain entities (POJOs), and nothing else. Everything builds correctly, and any references from classes in 'myproject-main' to entities in 'myproject-domain' are fine.

The problem is I have Hibernate hbm.xml files in 'myproject-main' that reference entities in 'myproject-domain'.

This is in 'myproject-main', along with all other Hibernate and Spring setup:

```
<class name="uk.co.luciditysoftware.myproject.domain.entities.User" table="`User`">

  <id name="id" column="`Id`" type="uuid-char">
    <generator class="assigned" />
  </id>

  <property name="firstName">
    <column name="`FirstName`" length="50" not-null="true" />
  </property>

  <property name="lastName">
    <column name="`LastName`" length="50" not-null="true" />
  </property>

</class>
```

and this class in in 'myproject-domain':

```
package uk.co.luciditysoftware.myproject.domain.entities;

import java.util.UUID;

public class User {
  private UUID id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public UUID getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

If I included the user entity in the 'myproject-main' project, everything works as expected, so there's nothing wrong with my Hibernate/Spring setup, it just has a problem finding the User entity when it is in a referenced project.

The expection stack raised when starting the project has

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.luciditysoftware.myproject.domain.entities.User
```

at the bottom with

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: class uk.co.luciditysoftware.myproject.domain.entities.User not found while looking for property
```

next in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out. I was referencing myproject-domain from my-project-main by going:

```
myproject-main -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add
```

and adding myproject domain there, but you also need to do:

```
Main menu -> Run -> Run Configurations... -> Apache Tomcat -> Tomcat v8.0 server -> Classpath tab -> Add Projects...
```

and add myproject-domain from there, as mentioned in this question: [calling a class in another project Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792812/calling-a-class-in-another-project-eclipse)