# Cucumber issue(Calling step defination from other java project )

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumberjs

My requirement is that i am keeping my step Definition  code in other Java Project and my runner class is in other java project..
I am not able to call step definition provided in other java project..
Please help how can i achieve the same

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, but it seems your problem is with the location of your source files? If this is the case, please describe the directory structure of your java projects, and how you are currently trying to use them.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If eclipse then look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792812/calling-a-class-in-another-project-eclipse

Comment: I don't know how did you organize the two projects when running.  If you merged two project source code together before running via some buid tool like: Ant or by manual.  It should not happen this issue.  Or you add the step definition project as a libray to the runner project,  It should not happen such issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got solved when i added Runner Class Java Project to Build Path of Step definition Project Build Path..
Then i was able to provide glue code path directly using package name from other java project..
Thanks for all comments Provided.