# Is it possible to import class file with default package?

Tags: java

I have created a project and **Hello.java** file without package name

```
public class Hello {
   public String sayHello(){
      return "Say Hello";
   }
}
```

I exported this project into **hello.jar**.

Now I have created another project and **Main.java** to call sayHello() method. I added hello.jar in classpath but the below code showing me an error 'Hello cannot be resolved to a type'

```
 public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Hello h=new Hello(); // Error
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335211/what-is-the-default-package-in-which-my-classes-are-put-if-i-dont-specify-it

Comment: You can't import classes from the default package.

Comment: That's the reason why Java have package naming convention. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: Related (duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/283816/1065197

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193226/how-to-import-a-class-from-default-package

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible due to the fact that your `Hello.java` class needs to be inside a package stored in your JAR file to enable you to reference it. The structure of your JAR should at least be

> hello.jar/packageName/Hello.java

after creating it like that it will be imported as

```
import packageName;
```

and you will be able to use classes from aformentioned package.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible.
Try giving package name to `Hello` java file and then create again jar and then write import statement in Main class file

```
package com;
public class Hello {
   public String sayHello(){
      return "Say Hello";
   }
}
```

and in `Main` class add  following line

```
import com.Hello;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Hello h=new Hello(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is a solution for the problem, it doesn't directly explain the reasons of this problem.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza - I hope my answer added some value to OP. Can you please explain more on reason ? It will be value addition for me.

Comment: Yes, check the link posted in my comment on OP's question.