# Why it complains when I import a self-defined package like below?

Tags: java

I have build two classes named PackageTest.java (in the desktop dir) and Employee.java (in the desktop/com/wenhu/corejava dir).

In the Employee.java file, I wrote in the first line:

```
package com.wenhu.corejava;
```

Then in the PackageTest.java file, I wrote in the first line:

```
import com.wenhu.corejava.*;
```

However, the compiler complains:

```
    PackageTest.java:8: error: cannot access Employee
        Employee harry = new Employee("Harry", 50000, 1989, 10, 1);
        ^
  bad class file: .\Employee.class
    class file contains wrong class: com.wenhu.corejava.Employee
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
1 error
```

Interestingly, if I wrote:

```
import com.wenhu.corejava.Employee;
```

The compiler is OK!
Could anyone tell me why this is happened? I though the wildcard * could represent the Employee Class...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _"class file contains wrong class: com.wenhu.corejava.Employee
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath."_ You messed up your project structure. make sure that `Employee.java` is in the `com/wenhu/corejava` directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

> bad class file: .\Employee.class
>
> class file contains wrong class: com.wenhu.corejava.Employee

Your setup is somehow messed up. It seems that you have a class file for Employee in your *current* directory.

The package name within the class file must match the file system location!

Comment: Haaah, I feel like drinking a big beer, I found that rat in the current directory, thank you so much for answering my noob question... It helps a lot!!!

Comment: Sure. And for the record: please dont forget about about accepting one of the answers.

Comment: oh, still have a question. Why it turns to be right after I import the whole path including the Employee, like import com.wenhu.corejava.Employee; why the compiler doesn't have the name confusion this time, even I still have the rat in the current directory?

Comment: I have to admit: I can't say. We would have understand all aspects of your setup completely. Like class path setup, folder structure, ...

Comment: The case `import com.wenhu.corejava.Employee` works because this is a "single-type-import" that shadows the `Employee` class of the current package. A wildcard import (type-import-on-demand) does not shadow the class `Employee` of the current package. See the JLS rules about shadowing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I get it!

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.wenhu.corejava;
```

This statement in the `Employee` class means that your class file `Employee.java`  must be located in the directory `com/wenhu/corejava/`. But in your case it is in the directory which your java compiler as root of all sources understand, i.e. the [default package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2335211/1113392).

To resolve your problem, either remove the package declaration mentioned above, [which is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7849421/1113392), or create the corresponding directory and move the source file `Employee.java` to it.