# (eclipse) is it okay to use other class in the same folder without importing?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have some questions for using the Eclipse Java IDE.

The classes `Link`, `LList` and the interface `List` are in the default package:

[image: folder]

I want to use `Link<E>` in class `LList<E>`. Can I just use it like in the picture without importing the class or creating a package?

[image: used in class]

Can I also implement the interface without importing the interface or creating a package?

How is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  All classes (including interfaces, & annotations) in the current folder are implicitly imported.  There is no need to explicitly import them.   This behaviour is an aspect of the Java language; it has nothing to do with Eclipse or any other IDE or build system.

Answer (score 0):

All three of them (`Link`, `LList`, `List`) are actually present in a package. Just this is a special case of a package, the unnamed (often called "default") package. It is not necessary to declare imports from the same package (and they fulfill this requirement).

btw. You might want to move to specific package, as using the default one is discouraged - [Is the use of Java's default package a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849421/is-the-use-of-javas-default-package-a-bad-practice) .

Comment: what is a default package? is it created automatically in eclipse when a folder or a project is created?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335211/what-is-the-default-package-in-which-my-classes-are-put-if-i-dont-specify-it