# Why servlet is not found in Tomcat folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to create the first servlet in tomcat following many examples on the internet but always gives me error 404. I already checked for other solutions but I don't understand the main problem.(sometimes give me error 500 also)

**link**:

> http://localhost:8080/Servlet/Hello

**folder**:

```
\--Tomcat
     \--webapps
          \--Servlet
               \--WEB-INF
                   \--web.xml 
                    \--classes
                        \--HelloWorld.class 
                         \--HelloWorld.java
```

**HelloWorld.java**:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Hello World copy!</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello World copy!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<web-app xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4">


<servlet>

<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>

</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>

<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Your servlet class is in the default package.

Comment: I have already read that page but I have not found a right solution. What do I have to do?

Comment: what does "Your servlet class is in the default package" mean?

Comment: Check [What is the default package in which my classes are put if I don't specify it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2335211/11748454)