# Why can't I import ZipFileManager and ConsoleHelper? These classes are public but in the other pocket

Tags: java

I am creating an archiver and have got the following problem:

[image]

can anybody explain please why do I have such a bug?

tried to drag all files out of command pocket to java pocket and everything worked. but I need them to stay in the command pocket

Comment: Looks like you're just missing some import statements? Your IDE should be able to suggest fixes for it, or you can manually write in the imports yourself. But to make a good question for this website, you need to [edit] to include text instead of an image.

Comment: @DanGetz my IDE doesn't suggest any fixes.
Here is what happends when I write the imports myself:
Class 'ZipFileManager' is in the default package

Comment: Oh OK, according to [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2335228/3004881), it's not possible to import them if they're not in a named package. Your solution, then, would be to put them in a package first.