# Java using functions in a file

Tags: java, methods

Ok really stupid question, but I have some methods defined in a file called x.java, which is in the default folder, and in the same folder, I have a file called z.java. I want to use the functions defined in x in z. When I try, it tells me the function is undefined. I tried to put `import x.java;` but it says x.java cannot be resolved. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check your classpath. Does it include the current directory? i.e the "."

Comment: I was able to successfully use x class's method in z.java without any import. My method in x.java has default access and I have created object for x class and called the method. Probably class path problem as Suresh Kumar mentioned.

Comment: issue this command set classpath=.;%classpath% in windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, I'd bet there's a good chance both of your source files defined classes in the *default* package (i.e., you don't explicitly define a package for them).

[You can't import a class that's in the default package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package).

Recommend you put your class `x` in a named package (e.g., foo.bar.x), then you can import it:

```
import foo.bar.x;
```

Comment: I don't know why he accepted this answer (though it is very good answer), it probably problem with classpath.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a file called x.java which compiles to x.class, you don't import by doing:

```
import x.java;
```

but you do

```
import x;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, if the two classes are in same package then there is no need to import the class as that class can be used without any import and without any error.