# Java application not run in Eclipse Galileo

Tags: java, eclipse, galileo

I have Eclipse Galileo. I created a new Java project but couldn't run the application. I get the following launch error:

> Selection does not contain a main type

[image: The sample error screenshot]

Comment: this is my java-version "java version "1.6.0_20"
"

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend creating classes in a specific `package`.

Comment: it was developed in defaullt package? why in specific package? Is there seems any special?

Comment: Look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package/283828#283828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the main method is shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Also, the following link may be beneficial for you:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Change the method signature to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your environment, there really is no entry point to your project. The `main` method in the screenshot does not have the `String[] args` parameter. This is not C/C#/C++. You have to specify the `String[] args` no matter if you use them or not.

Comment: I didn't use any command line arguments? May i know why java wants that?

Comment: *That* is the signature of the entry point method for starting a Java-based stand-alone application. I am not able to tell you why Java does not have an alternative zero-arg main method.