# Why should one name java packages in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why shouldn't we use the (default)src package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995212/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-defaultsrc-package)

I am beginning to code Java in Eclipse. I created a new project and noticed a default package.

What is the benefit of creating a new package (via right-clicking "src") and naming it say "com.johnhoffman.myproject"? My application seems to work just fine with the default package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why create your own package:

**Organisation**, If you put everything in the default package, after a few years you would have several thousand classes in the default package and finding anything would be just about impossible. It would make naming a new class difficult - you would need to check if the name was already used.

**Reuse by others** If everyone put everything in the default package, how would you distinguish between **your layout** class and **johns layout** class and **peters layout** class

I would try and give your package a sensible name - helps If you need to refer back to the code later.

```
i.e.
    shop.swing.exercise
rather than
    exercise1
```

also see

[Why shouldn't we use the (default)src package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995212/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-defaultsrc-package)