# IDL to java (Suns idlj) how to compile generated files?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, corba, idl

I have an .*idl interface:

```
interface Class1;

interface Class2
{
    typedef sequence<Class1> vector;
    Class2 create();
};

interface Class1
{
    typedef sequence<Class2> vector;
    Class1 create();
};
```

I compile it like this:

> idlj -fclient interface.idl

and it gives me **files**:

```
Class1Helper.java      Class2.java            interface.idl
Class1Holder.java      _Class1Stub.java   Class2Operations.java
Class1.java            Class2Helper.java  
Class1Operations.java  Class2Holder.java  _Class2Stub.java
```

and **catalogs**:

> Class1Package Class2Package

in Class1Package I have : `vectorHelper.java  vectorHolder.java` and in Class2Package I have: `vectorHelper.java  vectorHolder.java`. When I `cd`ed to Class1Package and tried to compile java files (with `javac *.java) I got errors:

> vectorHelper.java:3: '.' expected import Class2;
>                ^ vectorHelper.java:3: ';' expected import Class2;
>                 ^ vectorHelper.java:4: class, interface, or enum expected import Class2Helper;
>          ^ vectorHolder.java:3: '.' expected import Class2;
>                ^ vectorHolder.java:3: ';' expected import Class2;
>                 ^ 5 errors Class1Package$ javac *.java vectorHelper.java:3: '.' expected import Class2;
>                ^ vectorHelper.java:3: ';' expected import Class2;
>                 ^ vectorHelper.java:4: class, interface, or enum expected import Class2Helper;
>          ^ vectorHolder.java:3: '.' expected import Class2;
>                ^ vectorHolder.java:3: ';' expected import Class2;
>                 ^ 5 errors

What's wrong?

My whole project: http://www41.zippyshare.com/v/32339153/file.html

Comment: sounds like your code generator is not generating the import correctly, can you have a look at java code to see what the compiler is complaining about, like for example import ,

Comment: @Akash Yadav: yeah, I know that but I don't know what might be wrong, me whole project: http://www41.zippyshare.com/v/32339153/file.html. Could you take a look?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package) (look at accepted answer), basically from java 4 on you can no longer refer to a class (using an import statement) in an unnamed package (aka. default package) from a named package.

Modify your IDL compiler to have a module, is there a reason you don't have your interfaces inside a module already?