# Module dependancies in IntelliJ12 not working for packages

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a basic client/server/common project that I am working on in Intellij (Java).  I have tried to google this problem, and although people seem to have this same problem, or something like it, I have not found a solution yet that works.

The server, client, and common are each their own module.  I have set up module dependencies on the Common module for both the client and the server.

[image: Project Structure]

In the RunServer class, which is not associated with any package and is right at the src root, I can use Coordinates, which is also not associated with any packages and in the src root.  But I cannot use Coordinates for player, as player is nested in a package.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't I be able to use anything in the Common module if it is specified as a dependency for another module?  Does anyone know a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: [Don't use the default package.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)

Comment: Wow, I am not a clever man.  Thank you.