# Java what did I do wrong here?

Tags: java, methods, error-handling, arguments, undefined

I'm using command line arguments for this one:

```
public class Pg253E4 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(Average.average(args)); // This part is saying I don't have a method in Average called average(String[] argName)
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Nice job");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the the other class:

```
public class Average {
    public static double average(String[] arrayString) throws NullPointerException,NumberFormatException {
        double sum=0;
        double arrayStorage[] = new double[arrayString.length];

        for(int i = 0; i< arrayString.length; i++) {
            arrayStorage[i] = Double.parseDouble(arrayString[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<arrayString.length; i++) {
            sum += arrayStorage[i];
        }
        return (sum/arrayString.length);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why a syntax error pops up saying that I haven't declared or defined any method called `average(String[] argName)` in the `Average` class, when I clearly did.

Comment: is Average in your classpath?

Comment: Is `Average` in the same package as `Pg253E4`?  If not has `Average` been imported to `Pg253E4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new object of the `Average` type in your main class. To do this write the following line on your main method:
`Average a = new Average();`

And then change your `System.out.println(Average.average(args))` for
`System.out.println(a.average(args))`

Comment: Should not be necessary to create an object of type `Average`, the method `Average.average()` is static.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using packages you need to make sure `Average` is imported into your `Pg253E4` class:

```
import Average; // Assuming "Average" is not in a package.

public class Pg253E4
{
    // The rest of your stuff
}
```

Probably best to use at least one package though:

```
package yourpackage;

public class Pg253E4
{
    // The rest of your stuff
}

package yourpackage;

public class Average
{
    // The rest of your stuff
}
```

If `Pg253E4` and `Average` don't have enough in common to be in the same package then they should both be put in their own package, in which case you would have to import `Average` into `Pg253E4` again:

```
package yourfirstpackage;

import yoursecondpackage.Average;

public class Pg253E4
{
    // The rest of your stuff
}

package yoursecondpackage;

public class Average
{
    // The rest of your stuff
}
```

Comment: they are in the same package(the default package)

Comment: Java has a history of problems with the access of classes and methods when using the default package.  Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/283828/288341), [here](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4989710), and [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/import.html).  It is almost always recommended to use a package, not the default package.  Use packages correctly and you will not have to instantiate a class just to access one of its static methods as the answer you have selected has instructed you to do.