# ImageJ: How to use third-party plugins API?

Tags: imagej

In Eclipse, I'm using the already packed `ij.jar` instead of the source code. I added the `ij.jar` file as an external jar in Eclipse. Every plugin shipped in the original `ij.jar` works fine after I imported from `ij`.

Currently, I'm trying to use functions in the third-party plugin [StackReg](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/thevenaz/stackreg/). Does anyone know how I can import the classes inside `StackReg`? I've tried to add `StackReg_.jar` as an external jar. However, this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From quickly looking at the source of `StackReg` plugin, I see that the classes are in the default package. In java, importing classes from default package to a named package is not possible without using reflection.

Possible solutions are:

- Put your classes in the default package. Then you can use the classes in the default package without importing them. Note that using default package is bad practice in java.
- Use reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/561183/1903534
- Alter the `StackReg` plugin to not use the default package. But this might not be compatible with its license and your solution will not be compatible with the original jar.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try out reflection.