# Enum can not be resolved? Java

Tags: java, import, enums, resolve

I have 2 classed at different pages.

The object class:

```
public class Sensor {

  Type type;
  public static enum Type
  {
        PROX,SONAR,INF,CAMERA,TEMP;
  }

  public Sensor(Type type)
  {
  this.type=type;
  }

  public void TellIt()
  {
      switch(type)
      {
      case PROX: 
          System.out.println("The type of sensor is Proximity");
          break;
      case SONAR: 
          System.out.println("The type of sensor is Sonar");
          break;
      case INF: 
          System.out.println("The type of sensor is Infrared");
          break;
      case CAMERA: 
          System.out.println("The type of sensor is Camera");
          break;
      case TEMP: 
          System.out.println("The type of sensor is Temperature");
          break;
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Sensor sun=new Sensor(Type.CAMERA);
        sun.TellIt();
    }
    }
```

Main class:

```
import Sensor.Type;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Sensor sun=new Sensor(Type.SONAR);
    sun.TellIt();
}
```

Errors are two, one is Type can not be resolved other is cant not import. What can i do? I first time used enums but you see.

Comment: See Reimeus's answer which should be accepted (the class containing the `enum` cannot be in the default package). Or [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package).

Answer (score 10):

`enums` are required to be declared in a package for `import` statements to work, i.e. importing `enums` from classes in package-private (default package) classes is not possible. Move the enum to a package

```
import static my.package.Sensor.Type;
...
Sensor sun = new Sensor(Type.SONAR);
```

Alternatively you can use the fully qualified `enum`

```
Sensor sun = new Sensor(Sensor.Type.SONAR);
```

without the import statement

Answer (score 2):

For static way give proper package structure in the static import statement

```
import static org.test.util.Sensor.Type;
import org.test.util.Sensor;
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sensor sun = new Sensor(Type.SONAR);
        sun.TellIt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The static keyword has no effect on enum. Either use the outer class reference or create the enum in its own file.