# Using classes in my project that originate in a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

I'm using Eclipse on a Windows 7 64x machine. I've researched this problem and found many have had a similar one, but no solution I came across quite worked for me.

I'm working on a Project named `Assignment_1`, on a class named `Percolation`. I'd like to use the object `WeightedQuickUnionUF` which is inside a package contained within a jar file, named `algs4.jar`.

I seem to have added the Jar file I'm interested in to the build-path (it now appears under "Referenced Libraries"). The jar file `algs4.jar` resides in a folder named `lib` inside my project's folder.

However, when I try to declare an object of type `WeightedQuickUnionUF` inside my class, I get an error "`WeightedQuickUnionUF` cannot be resolved to a type".

I tried various `import` commands (including just `import WeightedQuickUnionUF` )before the class declaration and all of them yield the error "The import `so and so` cannot be resolved".

For example, this piece of code yields both of these errors. One at the `import` line, and another at the declaration of the `WeightedQuickUnionUF` object:

```
package assignment_1_package;
import algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;

public class Percolation {

    private int[][] grid;
    public int gridDimension;
    private int opensGrid[][];
    private WeightedQuickUnionUF model;

... //rest of class body here
```

This has baffled me for an entire day and I can't seem to figure this out. Thanks for your efforts.

Edit: here is a link to the class I wish to import: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/WeightedQuickUnionUF.java.html

Comment: can u share WeightedQuickUnionUF class?

Comment: here it is: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/WeightedQuickUnionUF.java.html

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the algs4.jar of the class http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/ , your import is incorrect you should do :

```
import WeightedQuickUnionUF;
```

**BUT** it's never a good idea to have class in the default package and it's actually **not allowed** to  import a type from the unnamed package: this gives a **compilation error**.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/packages.html#7.4.2:

> A type-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.2) imports all the
>   accessible (§6.6) types of a named type or package as needed. **It is a
>   compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package**.

So in your case to solve your issue just create your classes in the default package so you don't have to do the import at all.

Comment: I tried that import and I get the same error. You're right, this is where I got the jar file.
When I expand the jar file to see its classes, I first have to click through `(default package)`. Is it not considered a package?

Comment: You must have a problem with your Eclipse project setup.

Comment: Is it anyway related to having a `main` class? I don't currently have one in my project.
In any case, do you have any idea what could be wrong with my project setup? Thanks for the the input anyway. :)

Comment: indeed you are right, it's not allowed to import classes from the default package this gives a compilation error, just updated my answer

Comment: I see. It's very strange that a University would provide a jar file that cannot export its classes. It's just that this piece from their site regarding using the Jars says: "How can I classpath in the textbook libraries from the command line? If you use our Mac OS X or Windows installer, then you can automatically classpath in the textbook libraries using the commands `javac-algs4` and `java-algs4` (instead of `javac` and `java`)."

Comment: It just seems like it should be possible somehow, because if the only way to include the classes is to manually copy them, there would be no need to add them to the "Referenced Libraries" section, which is what they refer me to here: http://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/checklists/percolation.html

Comment: just create your own class in the default package as well, and it should work ok

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same class, had the same problem. Removing my equivalent to these two statements

```
 package assignment_1_package; 
    import algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;
```

resolved the problem.  That's to say the following now resolves correcly

```
 private WeightedQuickUnionUF model;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it helped adding

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdStats;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;
```