# java correct understanding of classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I am on linux and my folder structure is

```
java
  --main
      --Main.java
  --aux
      --pckg
          --Aux.java
```

Source code

**Main.java**

```
import pckg.Aux;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main main");
        Aux.method();
    }
    public static void method() {
        System.out.println("Main method");
    }
}
```

**Aux.java**

```
package pckg;
public class Aux {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Aux main");
        Main.method();
    }    
    public static void method() {
        System.out.println("Aux method");
    }
}
```

I try to compile this file with command
 
(in main directory)

```
javac Main.java -classpath .:../aux
```

So I understand it this way. I need to set classpath to "." which is my current directory (where Main.java is located) and to "../aux" because pckg.Aux class is there.

But I get this error:

```
../aux/pckg/Aux.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
Main.method();
^
  symbol:   variable Main
  location: class Aux
1 error
```

looks like Main class cannot be located from within Aux class. But path to main is in the classpath. So where am I wrong here?

Comment: not related to your problem, just want to know which OS you are using

Comment: Okay, I tried but not able to create a class with name AUX USing windows 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work. For an explanation, see: [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)