# use classes contained in a .jar file in a java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse and i have a library (.jar file). 
  I need to import it in my project.
I have already added it in my project (Build path..).
 Now my problem is that  there is a default package who contains  (.class files) in the library .
and i don't know how to use it (instanciate objects from this library) in my code.

thx a lot

Comment: your question isn't clear, add some more information before it gets closed

Comment: Oki i ve updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't, unless you extract those classes from the jar and put the classes themselves on your classpath. See also: [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)