# How do I import servlet class in jsp when package is default?

Tags: java

Wrote some code as a **Java Servlet** and I am now trying to use in  JSP. I wrote a class in a separate file which I was using, and I can't figure out how to get the JSP file to recognise the class. I guess it has something to do with importing. I gave the class a default package (no name of package) and I tried using `<%@ page import=".Register"%>` but I get an error: (Register is my servlet class name..) 
so tell me what if i do to import of default package in jsp.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: How about giving a package name and using it ?

Comment: Actually i know the syntax <%@ page import="packagename.classname"%> but i want to know when package name is not define means it is default then how to import servlet class in jsp??

Comment: Well default will be bad practice what about define package and import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import a class from a default package. It's a compile time error. See the [Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#7.5).

Or you can use `reflections`.
For Reflections You Can Visit SO link: [Reflections for importing class from default package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package/561183#561183).

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you need to look up [JSP Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr245/index.html) and I got idea that you need to specify the package name if you wanted to import into the JSP. I did not know until I read the document.