# How to import jar file by mac terminal

Tags: java, classpath

I try to import stdlib.jar in my project by terminal. The procedure is like this:

1. Move stdlib.jar to the folder "bin";
2. Add `import bin.stdlib.*` in the main class which residences in folder "src" and saved;
3. In terminal try `src> javac -cp '../bin/:stdlib.jar' MyClass.java` but failed to compile with the reason "package bin.stdlib does not exist". There are indeed many answers related to this issue online but I still cannot figure it out. Any advice is welcomed.

Comment: You don't important the "jar" file, you import it's contents...but of course, `StdLib` stores everything in the default package, brillant

Comment: You may also want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package) for the problems you are likely to have...