# Java Access Modifiers: Accessing default class from another packages

Tags: java, class, access-modifiers

How to access default class in some/another package using public class in that package.

For example,

my `Bank package` has 2 classes

1. `public class Bank { ... }`
2. `class Account { ... }`(default access modifier)

I need to access `Account` in another `package` called `Atm` using `Bank`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Refer these links:
[Link1]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm
[Link2]http://java-answers.blogspot.in/2012/01/access-specifiers-in-java.html
[Link3]http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/access-specifiers

Comment: Don't make it default. That means visible in current package only.

Comment: This is one of the tasks in the assignment to make it default. Otherwise, I would make it public)

Comment: Suggest you read the instructions for that task again ... because what you *think* you are being asked to do does not make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How import java classes inside the default package from the default package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676346/how-import-java-classes-inside-the-default-package-from-the-default-package)

Comment: I need to access default class using public class in the same package.

Comment: As written before: this assignment does not sound valid. If Atm is NOT in the same package as Bank and Account; the compiler will not allow you to use Account within Atm.

Comment: Accessing a default ("package protected") class from outside the package is not possible. This is nicely illustrated in [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052). If you want to keep some control of the `Account` instances within the `Bank` package, you can make the `Account` class public, but its constructor package protected (so that it can only be created from within the package) and then create a public account factory method in the `Bank` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per java's Rule for `Accessing class/method/instances`,

> the default things(class/method/instances) must not be visible into another
>   package.
>
> So, here in your case it's not possible to access it through another
>   package because default class not visible to there.
>
> default things visible within same package only where it's define/declare

Comment: So you mean that I cannot access it even I will create instance of it in public class?

Comment: Absolutely. Calling class knows nothing about type Account

Comment: default class is not visible to any where out side the package, so how will you create instance of it into public class (another package )  ?

Comment: 1. Create default class in public class in the same package 2. Access it in another package calling public class

Comment: @Atalyk are you talking about inner class(class within class) ?

Comment: @vishalgajera No, it is not

Comment: @Atalyk then do you mean, into same package both classes resides ?

Comment: @vishalgajera Yes, both Account and Bank classes are in the same package. I need to access Account methods in Atm class via Bank class. Like this one int balance = bank.getAccounts().get(customerID).getBalance(); but The Account is not visible

Comment: @Atalyk according your question asked, inside it you have clearly mentioned both class belongs into different packages. i.e. Bank package and Atm package. so please be clear first.

Comment: @vishalgajera Yes, there are 2 packages Bank (Bank.class - public, Account.class - private) and Atm (Atm.class - public). Then I need to access Account.class methods in Atm.class via Bank.class. Like this one int balance = bank.getAccounts().get(customerID).getBalance(); but The Account is not visible

Comment: @vishalgajera This is like real world ATM which uses bank to access Accounts.

Comment: please , point your corrent issue rightly, you issue is private Account class's member not accessible to Bank class, see private things can not be visible to out of class. so remove private access modifier so that Account class become's default which will work then

Comment: @vishalgajera I'm sorry for not being clear. Actually I need access Account.class methods in Atm.class which is another package. In order to do so I need to use public Bank.class which stores all accounts

Comment: okay, now do one thing, Bank class can access Account.class(make it default remove private modifier ) and then create one method into Bank class which will access Account, finally Atm class access Bank which will access Account.

Comment: @vishalgajera Can I call methods without creating Account object?

Comment: Yes, you can call Bank class's method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access this class from another package directly, but you can use [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and call Account methods by calling Bank methods

Comment: You understood me. This is what I want to do

Comment: create a public class in the same package with your default class then use Proxy pattern or Delegate pattern to access the default class. Eclipse supports auto generate delegate pattern. From other packages, you can access the default class via the public class

Answer (score 0):

Default access modifier for classes in java are, by definition, accessible only from within its package (see [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/)).

If you have access to source code you should consider to change the access level to public. Otherwise you can try to access that class via a public class in the same package.

```
package test.bankaccount;
public class Bank {
    public Account getAccount(int id) {
        //here goes the code to retrieve the desired account
    }
}

package test.bankaccount;
class Account {
    // class implementation
}
```

Anyway you should keep in mind that access restrictions always describes how application is meant to work. You should ask yourself why a specific class is not public.

If the classes are your own code, then ask yourself if the access restriction you put on represents correctly the way you intend the application to work.

Comment: Like this. Basically I want to call Account methods inside Atm class Account account = (Account)bank.getAccounts().get(customerID); but Account is not visible.

Comment: @Atalyk: are not Bank and Account in the same package?