# Can't reference generated-sources class outside of default package

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

I'm working with Google's Protocol Buffer (in combination with the Protocol Buffers maven plugin) which compiles a .proto file into a class. I can use the generated class in the default package perfectly, but not outside of it. I don't really know how to explain it any better so I'm going to show you some pictures.

[image: Working]
[image: Not working]

I've tried subclassing the Hrp class but that doesn't work (the generated class is final). It is also not an option to move the class every time I re-generate the Hrp class.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the generated class is `public final`. It contains an empty, `private` constructor.

I have also tried setting the generated sources package prefix for the generated sources folder but that also does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try specifying a package id in the protocol buffers definition (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#package) and then importing from the package id Java. You can import the default package id in Java

Comment: That's what I ended up doing and it seems to work now. Thank you!

Comment: I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a **package** id to your Protocol Buffers definition. See [Protocol Buffers Package](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#package)

i.e.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package MyPackage;
option optimize_for = SPEED;

message Product {
   repeated ASale sale = 1; 
}
```

Then when you Generate the *Java~Protocol~Buffers* code (using protoc), it will be in package **MyPackage** and you will be able to import it into your java code in the normal way.

In java, you **can not** import anything from the **Default package**; which I believe is your problem. See [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)