# How to access non-static class fields in a package from the (default package)?

Tags: java, package, class-visibility

So I have this class (let's call it "A") with this `get()` method which returns a class field, and which I want to access from another class ("B"). **Important: both classes are `abstract`.** These classes are in the same `package` (`package private` for all `A` and `B` members). The `Main` class has no package (or better, the default one).

*[before: twisted and useless description]*

I need from `B` class to access `A`'s `get()` method.

Tried with:

1) non-static call `Aobj.get()` starting from the `main`-located root object, but it seems to want the static call (weird, none of the members is `static`);

2) tried to access it statically and I got the `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field` error (of course).

...so I'm stucked, still getting the accessing syntax error, both ways I try. Any suggests?

**EDIT :**

So I came to an end. I'll now try to explain my errors.

*Basically*, the problem was I wanted to access an object located in the `Main` class (default package) from a class within a package. So I got a visibility problem.

In other circumstances, I would have resolved importing the class, but I figured out that [you cannot import a class located in the default package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package), so I created a `main` package and imported `Main` class in `B` class.

The worst mistake I kept making was *thinking I had to access the* `main.main(String[])... etc ...Aobj` *starting from the* `main` *itself*, which is a **really really bad thought** (still can't figure out how I thought it).

In fact, like Stephen C pointed out:

> The is true irrespective of the situation with packages, and irrespective of the path you take through other classes.

Finally, the code example... to be honest, the code is now really different from the days I wrote this question, and honestly I can't reproduce the faulty conditions since I don't remember all the faulty logic I was trying to achieve. (My fault.) I only wish to have explained myself properly this time.

Thanks to everyone to tried to help.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If B's `get()` method is not `static` then you need an instance of `B` if you want to call the method; e.g.

```
  B b = ....
  b.get();
```

The is true *irrespective* of the situation with packages, and *irrespective* of the path you take through other classes, etcetera.  (Though I'm not sure I entirely understand your "prose" description  of all of that ...)

Comment: I tried to do my best to describe it, but I understand it can be difficult to achieve the situation without a code example. I'll try to add one, thanks for now

Comment: Example code would definitely be a clearer way to express that, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Just from what you've described, (without code), you need access to an instance of `b`. There are a couple of ways this could go. If the method in `A` in question could use a different `B` instance for each call, just add a `B` argument to that method:

```
public class B {

    public int get() { //Or whatever the return type of get is
        //...
    }

}

public class A {

    public int methodThatNeedsABInstance(B instance) {
        int x = instance.get(); //Can call get method
    }

}
```

Which is then called by:

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A();
a.methodThatNeedsABInstance(b);
```

If each `A` instance should use the same `B` instance for all of it's calls, make it a field of type `B`:

```
public class A {

    private B instance;

    //Constructors, setters and getters for b as necessary    

    public int methodThatNeedsABInstance() {
        int x = instance.get(); //Can call get method
    }

}
```

Comment: Very helpful, however I can not instanciate `A` nor `B`: they're both `abstract`.