# intellij doesnt find classpath after moving package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

In Intellij I added a class `Geometry.class` as library root file (via `project-structure/modules/dependencies`) and it totally worked out for my inheriting class `Volume.java` in the default package.
Now after moving the Volume down into a package `blatt03` it cant find Geometry anymore.

Do you guys know why thats the case? Normally the library shouldn't be available only to the default package, right?

I already tried Invalidate cache and restart.

[image: picture of my IDE]

Comment: Is `Geometry.class` also in the default package in the Library?

Comment: yes, i guess. I dont have package is my lib folder. I didnt know how you could create those

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less a duplicate of [How to access java-classes in the default-package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)

The core statement is *You can’t use classes in the default package from a named package.*

So the class `Geometry.class` must not be contained at root level (default package). Just put it in a package.

Comment: are you sure thats the same problem? Because I want to access .class files from the library. I just added a picture to my post to make it clearer

Comment: HI yes, this is the problem. So if you have control over the library containing the `Geometry`-class, move it into a package. If you don't have control over it, maybe the maintainer can move it.