# How to import the classes within a jar file in the folder of resources, to another class within a package?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I have used Intellj to create a project(Spring, actually, but I found this problem to have nothing between **Java** project and **Spring** project) whose hierachy lies below:

- project_name

  - *src*

    - *main*

      - *java*

        - *com.x.y*

          - *controller_package*

            - **controller_class.java**
          - *model_package*

            - **model_class.java**
      - *resources*

        - ***THIS.JAR***

I don't quite understand, as on the level of **java directory**, I could create a java class which could directly use the class within ***THIS.JAR***, while the file within those packages, i.e., **controller_class.java**, I could not find the java class within ***THIS.JAR***. In the former case, when I enter **THAT_CLASS** in **THIS.JAR**, the tooltip will pop up with *Default package*.

***This.jar*** is a jar file created by myself from another project, I used Maven and pom.xml has been configured. This .jar contains some other modules like **postgresql/antlr**. But on both levels of **java directory** and **controller_package** I could import these modules. I have been searched around and found no solution. As a greenhand to Java, it has ruined my day and please, if there is someone who can help?

Comment: It seems that your classes in "this.jar" are in the default package (i.e. don't have a `package x.y;` statement). According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package you can't use classes in the default package from classes within a package.

Comment: When working with Maven, just add your libraries as dependency in your `pom.xml`. Never ever add a JAR to resources.

Comment: @ThomasKläger my desired classes in this.jar exactly have no form like com.xxx.yyy, and the contained classes which could be imported are all in the form of com.xxx.yyy. I suppose this to be the reason...But I am not quite sure how to pack that project into form of x.y in IDEA, as there are ANTLR4 which I need and is utmost hard to change the directory...

Comment: @ThomasKläger I tried to use reflections, but it seemed not be able to find the class in default package... strange. Anyway, great thanks

Comment: @GyroGearless thanks for advice. After multiple attempts on configuring pom.xml, I suppose that default package is the reason

Comment: With ANTLR4 your grammar files should contain a `@Header { package x.y; }` statement and the files should be placed within the package structure like other source files. Then the maven-antlr plugin will create the java files within the correct structure (see https://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/examples/simple.html) - no need for them to be in the unnamed/default package.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Can't thank you more, you literally save my day

Answer (score 0):

**if used Eclipse**

you can add jar file

**1- select right click on your project and select proprieties**

**2- select java build path**

**3- select module path and then click on Add External JARS**

and then check
JRA SYSTEM LIBRARY
if the jra file exist or not