# Error: Main method not found despite I have declared a main function

Tags: kotlin

I am new to kotlin and I am trying to use main function together with a class.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var demo = Person("Hello", 10)

    println(demo)
}

private class Person (name: String, age: Int){
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init {
        this.name = name
        this.age = age
    }
}
```

Although I have declared the `main` function, the compiler is still looking for the static main method in the class that I have defined, `Person`, and I got this error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Person, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://pl.kotl.in/MxpZrlMke

Probably problem in the way you're running this code?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: I just do `kotlinc Person.kt` and then `java Person`. My version of `kotlinc` is `info: kotlinc-jvm 1.5.20 (JRE 16.0.1+9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java Person` is the problem, you are specifically telling it to look for the `static void main` method there. Top-level functions from `Person.kt` [will be compiled into a `PersonKt` class by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions) and so you should run `java PersonKt`.

Also, the unnamed package you get by not specifying any package [is weird in some ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package), so I would recommend adding a package declaration from the start (and running `java your.package.PersonKt`).